# AsyncStorage not storing data

Tags: javascript, react-native, vue.js, vue-native

I have looked at the documentation on asyncStorage through but don't understand why it is not saving my data. I am using Laravel for API and Vue native(a wrapper around react-native).
When a user signs up I pass the token generated this way

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
...
handleRegister() {
  axios.post('/api/mobile-register', this.formData).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    var token = response.data


    async(token) => {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@user_Token', token)
      } catch (e) {
        // save error
      }

      console.log('Done.')
    }
    console.log('User Registered!');

  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
},
```

The token is returned and logged as a string and the user is registered but the token is not saved.
I tried to check the saved token using this in the mounted hook and attached to a button but it returns null

```
 astore(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_Token').then((res) => console.log(res))

  },
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make more sense to remove the anonymous function that does not exist and simply make the callback the async function:

```js
axios.post('/api/mobile-register', this.formData).then( async response => {
  console.log(response.data);
  var token = response.data
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@user_Token', token)
  } catch (e) {
    // save error
  }
  console.log('Done.')
  console.log('User Registered!');
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: I  am getting not a function error, maybe i am not writing it correctly. But if I remove the anonymous function and just do ````if(token ! == ''){AsyncStorage.setItem('@user_Token', token)}````. It works and it is saved.

Comment: You can simplify your code. I've changed my answer.